# Javascript setAttribute not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement the includeHTML() function provided by w3schools.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

It works properly if I manually create a div, like in the site:

```
<div w3-include-html="awebsite.html"></div>
```

However if I try to create a div with Javascript then it is not working, for example:

```
var htmlIncluder = document.createElement("div");
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("w3-include-html", "awebsite.html");
document.body.appendChild(htmlIncluder);
```

Is it because the div does not have the w3-include-html attribute by default? What should I do to make this work?

Thanks for help!

Update, this is my index.html, to make it more clear in which order things appear, it also shows the includeHTML function:

```
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--this is the manually created div that works-->
<div w3-include-html="2.html"></div>
<!-- divs created with js.js have the correct attribute but don't show any content -->
<script src="js.js"></script>
<script>
includeHTML();
</script>
</body>
```

Here's the part where the js.js creates the div that should contain the includeHTML(); content. The div is added to a cell that is added to a grid, and the whole thing is added to the document.body. It's visible in the site so it correct, for example the text element "middle" is visible. The page is divided to header, middle and footer as a grid all of that is also visible.

```
cell.className = "middle";
cell.id = "middle-"+cellIdNo;
var text = document.createTextNode("middle");
var htmlIncluder = document.createElement("div");
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("w3-include-html", "2.html");
cell.appendChild(text);
cell.appendChild(htmlIncluder);
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn to use your browser's error console before you do anything else. It will save you *so* much time. It would have told you what was wrong here.

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages.

Comment: Hmm…Chrome gives me: *Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined* and Safari: *ReferenceError: Can't find variable: body*

Comment: Yes it is because I first forgot to write the document. I updated the question now.

Answer (score 2):

It because there's no such thing as `body.[something]`, the element doesn't get even added to the DOM.

use `document.body` or `document.querySelector('body')` etc...

```js
var htmlIncluder = document.createElement("div");
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("w3-include-html", "awebsite.html");
document.body.appendChild(htmlIncluder);
```

UPDATE : Since the question got updated.

I don't understand by `It's not working` because it down.

However, since it's not a built-in property into the [HtmlElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

Custom properties can be accessed through `attributes property` or `getAttribute() method`

```js
var htmlIncluder = document.createElement("div");
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("customattribute", "Custom Attribute Value");
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("class", "div");
document.body.appendChild(htmlIncluder);

var el = document.querySelector('.div');
console.log(el.getAttribute('CustomAttribute'));
console.log(el.attributes['customattribute'].value);
```

```css
.as-console-row-code{font-size:1.2em !important;}
.div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know, it wasn't from the actual code, so that is not the problem. Sorry for making an error there. The element I created gets added so that is not the reason.

Comment: As far as I know the problem is that there is no attribute w3-include-html for the div. So how can I create that with javascript, clearly it is possible with manually creating the div but how can I do the same with JS?

Comment: Thanks for answer! What I mean by "not working" is that the div is not showing the html it should. This is the div copied from firefox inspector:
<div w3-include-html="2.html"></div> And it was created with javascript. However it is not showing anything.

But if I create a div like this:
<div w3-include-html="2.html"></div> 
in plain html manually straight into index.html it works! I don't understand why. They are exactly the same but for some reason the first one doesn't show the includeHTML() function.

Comment: What I noticed tho is that the div I created with javascript is in the inspector after the includeHTML() function call. I don't know why as my script in the index.html  is before the function call! Might this be the reason, and if so how to fix it? My own javascript is before the function call already so I don't understand why they change places in the inspector.

Comment: Do you understand what `includeHTML();` does ? is it the same as the one in w3school ?

Comment: Yeah, everything is from w3school, also made sure that the order of execution is correct. Check my comment to the latest answer.

Comment: So the problem is that those websites doesn't appear right ?

Comment: The problem is that with the JS created div the content doesn't appear at all. With the manually created div everything works alright. I said in other comment that some why in firefox's inspector my js script and includeHTML appear in wrong order even though in the index.html they are in correct order. I updated the question with index.html

Comment: Now i'm really confused, Can you update your question with the full html and js ?

Comment: Thanks for help but I found the solution :) Posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `document.body` instead ofc`body`

```js
var htmlIncluder = document.createElement("div");
var t = document.createTextNode("test"); // only for testing
htmlIncluder.appendChild(t); // only for testing
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("w3-include-html", "awebsite.html");
document.body.appendChild(htmlIncluder);
```

Comment: I made a mistake when writing the question, fixed it now. The mistake I made here is not the actual reason for this not to work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `includeHTML` function loops through the document's elements, and looks for elements that have the attribute `w3-include-html`.

Where in your code do execute `includeHTML();`?

The function needs to be executed **after** you have created the div elements with javascript.

The code below will probably work:

```
var htmlIncluder = document.createElement("div");
htmlIncluder.setAttribute("w3-include-html", "awebsite.html");
document.body.appendChild(htmlIncluder);

includeHTML();
```

Comment: This is my index.html, the js.js creates a grid where I have the div which has the correct attribute. <body>
<div w3-include-html="2.html"></div>
<script src="js.js"></script>
<script>
includeHTML();
</script>
</body> So the first div in the body is what I do manually which works, and the others made with JS don't.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by moving the includeHTML function from index.html to my js.js file. And adding there this bit of code in the window.onload = function() {}:

```
if( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    includeHTML();
}
```

Now it calls the function when the divs are created. Still don't know why it didn't work from the index.html.